# Elgato USB video capture device #10020840 - I can't tell if it's working, I don't think it is. (Ubuntu 14.04 x64)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, capture

I have Avidemux-qt 2.6.8 installed, but under the "video decoder" section, it just says XXXXX.

I'm not sure if the drivers are even working for the device. In Windows, I would just check out the Device Manager and see if there were any hardware/driver errors, but I don't know how to do that in Ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[This](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815131011) is the device I speak of:

- **Brand**: Elgato
- **Model**: Video Capture
- **PerformanceResolution Support**: 640x480 (4:3) or 640x360 (16:9)
- **Audio**: AAC, 48 kHZ, 128 kBit/sec
- **CompatibilitySystem Requirements**: Mac: OS X 10.6.8 or later. PC: Windows 7 or later, 2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo (or comparable), sound card
- **SpecificationSpecification**: Elgato Video Capture automatically detects NTSC, SECAM, PAL and PAL/60 video formats for worldwide compatibility.

  Video format Mac Software: H.264 at 1.4 MBit/sec or MPEG-4 at 2.4 MBit/se
  Video format PC Software: H.264 at 1.4 MBit/se

  Generated files can be synced with video capable iPads, iPods, iPhones and Apple TV and can be edited in iMovie or Windows Live Movie Maker without re-encoding.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0fd9:0037 Elgato Systems GmbH Video Capture v2
```

Comment: Have you tried opening it in a camera recording app (like cheese)? Also, what does `lsusb` return?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat lsusb says "Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0fd9:0037 Elgato Systems GmbH Video Capture v2" and cheese does recognize the USB device (Elgato video capture V2 /dev/video0), but errors with the message "there was an error playing video from the webcam"

Comment: It's obviously detected. That's good. You just need a program to capture the video from it now...

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Yeah, but both Avidemux and Cheese error when trying to capture video, how can I figure out what is going on?

Comment: Sounds like you need a video codec...

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Do you have a recommended codec to use and how to install it?

Comment: What kernel version do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17565/discussion-between-malon-and-whaaaaaat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to tell if a device is detected is through `lsusb` and `/dev`. It's not always failsafe, though.

If `lsusb` shows an entry for the device (and it is identified correctly), the kernel is detecting it, fixing one part of the problem.

If `/dev` shows an entry for it (in this case, `/dev/video*` (replace * with a number)), then it is exposed to the system and ready to use.

In your case, [as determined by chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17565/discussion-between-malon-and-whaaaaaat), your card is just not compatible. The system detects it and makes it ready, but no program can read it. It sounds like a propritrary communication codec, kind of like what those one-time camcorders have.

Elgato is not compatible with Linux (even with custom drivers), so this is sadly a dead cause.

---

You can use a standard Sony camcorder as a pass-through device.

Hook up the RCA cables to the connector jack, and a DV cord to the DV port.

Se the camera to VTR mode and change the "RCA > Digial" mode in the camera menu to ON.

Comment: GUVCview crashes with a segfault at startup, and kino says "NO AV/C compliant cam connected or not switched on?" Here is the startup info for non-root guvcview: http://pastebin.com/BfKwsAY7 and here is the root startup: http://pastebin.com/zXznxrgT. Nonroot ends in segfault, root doesn't. Kino gives error about no write access to /dev/raw1394 if not run as root, otherwise just says no available device found. Additionally, the command "$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video0" runs through VLC, which has basically every codec under the sun, but still no joy :(

Comment: Final Answer: Elgato devices are incompatible with Linux. Even tried to compile new Video4Linux drivers to no avail from here: http://www.linwik.com/installing_the_latest_v4l_tv_tuner_drivers_for_ubuntu_12.04 but still no joy. I guess I have to buy a different device. Sucky, but not much else can be done. Thanks though!